# Make a CStatic not scrollable MFC

Tags: c++, scroll, mfc, dialog

I have an MFC dialog class inheriting from another one already having a scroll implementation.

In this class I'm displaying several CStatics and would like to know if it would be possible to "freeze" one or make it unscrollable.

I have already tried making a child window of the first one so I could create a CStatic in it with no scroll but it's not really what I'm looking for, I need to do it on the same dialog.

Comment: It might be useful to see a screen grab of what you have described and if appropriate the RC data for the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your `CStatic` controls have `WS_HSCROLL` or `WS_VSCROLL` styles. You can see those styles with `Spy++` tool.

If they are there, simply removing them will do the job.

If they are not (some custom scrolling implementation?), we would need more details.

Comment: Not sure (question is unclear) but I *think* OP wants the new `CStatic` not to *move* when the dialog scrollbars are dragged.

Comment: @AdrianMole we may never know :)